# How to avoid for loop when computing xts weighted sum?

Tags: r, xts

How could I avoid for loop calculating xts weighted sum as I am trying to do below:

```
library(xts)

thetaSum <- function(theta, w=c(1, 1, 1)) {
    sum(coredata(theta)*rev(w))
}

n <- 10
tmpVec <- rep(1, n)
tmpDates <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length = n, by = "day")
theta <- xts(tmpVec, order.by=tmpDates)

N <- 3
thetaSummed <- xts(rep(NA, n), order.by=tmpDates)

for (i in N:n) {
    thetaTemp <- theta[(i-N+1):i, ]
    thetaSummed[i] <- thetaSum(thetaTemp, w=rep(1, N))
}

thetaSummed
```

N is a look back period smaller than n.

What are some fast alternatives for for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rollapply`.

```
rollapplyr(theta, width=3, FUN=thetaSum, fill=NA)
```

Comment: Just to expand on that: `rollapplyr` is a wrapper for `rollapply` that does `align="right"` (i.e. the `(i-N+1):i` in your original code). By default `rollapply` does `align="center"`, and by adding `align="left"` it would do the equivalent of `i:i+2` in your code (assuming you also change the loop to `for(i in 1:(n-N+1)){...}`)